# Do I get updates for Kubuntu 16.04 after April 2019?

Tags: 16.04, package-management, updates, kubuntu

I'm using Kubuntu 16.04.6 with the kernel 4.4.0-143. On the Kubuntu website, it is stated that the support will be ended by April 2019, but most of the packages and kernel updates are based on Ubuntu repository (almost all, except for KDE related packages), the repositories:

```
Get:18 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease [107 kB]                                                 
Get:19 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [109 kB]   
Get:16 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease [109 kB]
Hit:13 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                                                 
Hit:14 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
```

Do I get security updates and kernel updates (OS centered updates, not KDE centered) after April 2019?

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/967169/why-does-kubuntu-and-xubuntu-16-04-lts-support-end-sooner-than-the-official-ubun for an explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run

`ubuntu-support-status --show-all > ~/Desktop/support.txt`

to get an idea of how long various packages will be supported.

I'm on **K**ubuntu 1**8**.04 and the summary at the top of the (long) output of that command looks like this:

```
Support status summary of 'kububb':

You have 1298 packages (55.3%) supported until April 2023 (Canonical - 5y)
You have 933 packages (39.8%) supported until April 2021 (Community - 3y)
You have 2 packages (0.1%) supported until April 2021 (Canonical - 3y)

You have 1 packages (0.0%) that can not/no-longer be downloaded
You have 113 packages (4.8%) that are unsupported
```

Note that packages categorized as *unsupported* may actually be unsupported or it maybe that the package maintainer hasn't specified the support status and the package may still be currently maintained. Also, packages derived from ppas are listed as "unsupported". For example, I have *google-chrome-stable* and *libreoffice-core* which are from actively supported ppas listed as unsupported.

Comment: thank you very much for your response!

the output of command is this:

 `You have 640 packages (22.5%) supported until آوریل 2019 (Community - 3y) `
 `You have 56 packages (2.0%) supported until آوریل 2021 (Community - 5y) `
 `You have 1784 packages (62.8%) supported until آوریل 2021 (Canonical - 5y) `

thank you again for hopeful information!

Comment: You're welcome! So go through the output and see which packages important to you will or won't be supported after April 2019.

Comment: just did it, most of them are for KDE related packages, so i think i might stick up on 16.04 till 2020.

Comment: _“the summary at the top of the (long) output”_ If you leave out the `--show-all` option, you’ll get just this summary.