# How to make baloo index .org files

Tags: baloo

I just installed Kubuntu 16.04 on a new laptop with an M2 drive and for the first time ever for me, Baloo is working very well.

However, it never returns matches from any of my .org files (plain-text files with org-mode formatting).

Looking at ~/.config/baloofilerc, there is no mention to exclude .org files, and Baloo finds matches in other plain-text files (.tex, for example).

Edit: I have now observed that it also does not return results from .c files! And .c files are also not excluded in baloofilerc.

The files I expect to find are not in hidden dot folders.

More information: I also checked the output of `balooctl config list excludeFilters` and `balooctl config list excludeMimetypes`, and there is no mention of org files there. Org files have a `text/plain` MIME type, so they should not be different from other files. If I copy a file important.org to important.txt, then Baloo immediately finds strings inside it, but not from the .org file.

Is there any way to *force include* a certain file extension or file type?

Comment: Where are these .org files located? Baloo will not index files and folders within dot folders such as *~/.config*, and *~/.local*..

Comment: I'll look around to see if I find anything but baloo's documentation is pretty slim! By the way, why did you go with 16.04 and not 18.04? There are genuine improvements in 18.04.

Comment: And here's a [recent bug](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=391677) with a similar issue proposing the use of *kfind* instead when searching in Dolphin. But again, most recent links may not apply to 16.04. Or consider using *recoll*.

Comment: Oh, and Kubuntu 16.04 LTS is supported for only three years from the date of release although you may still get updates to packages directly supported by Canonical: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1129661/do-i-get-updates-after-april-2019-kubuntu-16-04

Comment: In case I don't find a solution, I could try out kfind instead. Thanks for the hint. (And the reason I use 16.04 is because I need ROS Kinetic, which is only available for 16.04.)