# Thunar sometimes transforms a folder to a file in Xubuntu 16.04, 16.10, 18.04 LTS, and 18.10

Tags: xubuntu, directory, thunar

I have some scripts that creates folders by using `mkdir`:

```
...
mkdir bin
cd bin
mkdir make
...
```

It works perfectly most of the time. However, for unknown reasons, sometime, the just-created folders appear as a file in Thunar, a really annoying problem.

I can navigate into the newly made folder using the command line and the traditional `cd`, then run `ls` and other CLI commands.

**Questions:**

1. do you know what causes the problem?
2. do you know how to prevent it?
3. is it a Xubuntu issue or it is related to other Ubuntu dis?

**OS details:**
The problem was observed in XUbuntu 16.04, 16.10, 18.04 LTS and finally in 18.10.

Comment: Question updated. Tomorrow in the office I can add a screenshot

Comment: The file manager of all three was Thunar https://docs.xfce.org/xfce/thunar/start  but all those versions reached their end of public support. See https://askubuntu.com/a/967184/197910 and https://kubuntu.org/news/trusty-14-04-lts-end-of-life-and-end-of-kubuntu-support-for-xenial-16-04-lts/ Currently supported versions are 19.04 (in support until Jan. 2020) and 18.04 LTS (in support until Apr 2021).

Comment: No reasons, it is just an example (the folder are created at different time). However it give the same error after some changes in the script.

Comment: @K7AAY, same problem with 18.04.3 LTS

Comment: Then I'd file a bug report.