# Does support for Kubuntu 20.04 end in 2023?

Tags: kubuntu, lts

I've got a (K)ubuntu 20.04 system, as far as I can see:

```
$ cat /etc/lsb-release 
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=20.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=focal
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS"
```

and I'm getting this notification in my tray area:

```
Upgrade available
Ubuntu on 22.04.1 LTS.
This version will stop receiving updates and security fixes in 124 days.
```

First, what is "this version"? 22.04.1 LTS or the current installed version (unidentified in the message, but 20.04.5 LTS as shown above)?

Second, I thought LTS means 5 year support, so it doesn't seem to agree with any of them. So what's the catch here? Is it a bogus message or what?

Comment: "*I thought LTS means 5 year support*" See the [Kubuntu 20.04 Release Notes](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/FocalFossa/ReleaseNotes/Kubuntu), which has been consistent and very clear on this topic.

Comment: Ubuntu release statements & announcements in my view are pretty clear; ie. https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2022/09/01/ubuntu-20-04-5-lts-released/ states "*Maintenance updates will be provided for 5 years for Ubuntu Desktop, Ubuntu Server, Ubuntu Cloud, and Ubuntu Core. All the remaining flavours will be supported for 3 years. Additional security support is available with ESM (Extended Security Maintenance).*" ie. Kubuntu being a *flavor* has 3 years. That matches Kubuntu release notes https://wiki.ubuntu.com/FocalFossa/ReleaseNotes/Kubuntu but partial support can be included by MOTU's for 5 years

Comment: (*I ran out of space in last comment*), but I recommend reading @C.S.Cameron's answer, though technically Pilot6's is 100% accurate.  The 3 years is *guaranteed* support provided by the *flavor* team, wider Ubuntu community support can continues for the full five years (C.S.Cameron's point!) such as here, it's just less support.  Lubuntu (*another flavor of Ubuntu*) try to describe it in the release cycle found on this page - https://lubuntu.me/downloads/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does Kubuntu and Xubuntu 16.04 LTS support end sooner than the official Ubuntu EOL date?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/967169/why-does-kubuntu-and-xubuntu-16-04-lts-support-end-sooner-than-the-official-ubun)

Comment: To see what packages are in universe (3 year support) run:

   aptitude search "~i" -F "%s# %p" | grep universe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kubuntu LTS has a 3-year support. For 20.04 it will end in April 2023.

You can upgrade to Kubuntu 22.04.

Comment: I'm also getting the message. I installed Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and then added the kubuntu-desktop package. Did installing that package cut 2 years of support from my Ubuntu 20.04 LTS installation?

Comment: @TylerHam Your Ubuntu 20.04 LTS system will still get security packages& fixes, ie. be it a Kubuntu 20.04 ISO install, or a Ubuntu 20.04 ISO install with `kubuntu-desktop` added, so the packages from the *main* repository (which are all included on Ubuntu ISOs) get 5 years of fixes, however, flavors like Kubuntu use packages from *universe* which has only 3 years guaranteed; though a MOTU can correct issues up to 5 year mark, those will have ended support. You'll be on a partially supported system after April 2023; use `ubuntu-security-status` to explore these details on your system!

Answer (score 2):

### Ask Ubuntu EoSS for Flavors

Ask Ubuntu supports Ubuntu LTS flavors for the same amount of time as Vanilla LTS Ubuntu, that is five years.

See: https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/19617/43926

Specifically:

> Point is that we never intended to follow the '3 year LTS' - we
> intended to support the full 5 years even for the flavors, which is
> what we've always done. My answer goes in depth to explain the
> difference and what it means, THEN what we will be doing with Ask
> Ubuntu and how we'll handle it differently than a given flavor team ;)
> –
>  
> Thomas Ward

Kubuntu 20.04 will be supported by AU until April 2025.